# What does this joke mean?

Tags: notation

I saw this written on a blackboard in the math department building the other day:

Gas Law: $PV=nRT$

Ideal Gas Law: $(P)(V)=(n)(R)(T)$

I know the ideal gas law is something from chemistry, but I'm assuming this is meant to be some sort of joke involving math. Any ideas?

Comment: It's simply, in commutative algebra, the ideal generated by a element $a$ is usually denoted $(a)$.

Comment: And people say we don't have good jokes. Fancy that.

Comment: I don't like "gassy" jokes so much ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a ring, "$(a)$" is common notation for the principal *ideal* generated by $a$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal.)

Comment: But if the gas law is the equality $PV=nRT$, then the ideal gas law would be $(PV=nRT)$. The joke doesn't work.

Comment: @Git Ugh, no, that would be the gas law ideal. A horse race is a race for horses, and the ideal gas law is the gas law for ideals.